# Is it possible send HTTP/2 GET request with socket?

Tags: python, sockets, http2

I need to use HTTP/2 protocol in Python but all libs which support it can't send request with HTTPS proxy. Only HTTP.
How can I send it with socket and HTTPS proxy?

Comment: You would need to actually implement the HTTP/2 protocol which is way more complex than HTTP/1 - and far too complex to describe it here (just study the actual standard). But at the end the protocol is send over a socket, like HTTP/1. So it is possible but complex. Just  have a look at libraries like [hyper](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper) to get the idea of how it can be done.

Comment: *"but all libs which support it can't send request with HTTPS"* - are you sure? curl supports proxies over HTTPS (instead of only HTTP) for years so I would expect PycURL to support this too.

Comment: I only know hyper and httpx. I will read about PycURL